# How can one make an ellipse in react-leaflet?

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to draw an ellipse on a map made using `react-leaflet`, which has built-in support for circles and rectangles.

To achieve this, I am using code to produce an ellipse in (non-react) `leaflet` from [here](https://github.com/jdfergason/Leaflet.Ellipse), that I have adapted and pasted below:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';


L.SVG.include ({
    _updateEllipse: function (layer) {
        var // c = layer._point,
            rx = layer._radiusX,
            ry = layer._radiusY,
            phi = layer._tiltDeg,
            endPoint = layer._endPointParams;

        var d = 'M' + endPoint.x0 + ',' + endPoint.y0 +
            'A' + rx + ',' + ry + ',' + phi + ',' +
            endPoint.largeArc + ',' + endPoint.sweep + ',' +
            endPoint.x1 + ',' + endPoint.y1 + ' z';
        this._setPath(layer, d);
    }
});

L.Canvas.include ({
    _updateEllipse: function (layer) {
        if (layer._empty()) { return; }

        var p = layer._point,
            ctx = this._ctx,
            r = layer._radiusX,
            s = (layer._radiusY || r) / r;

        this._drawnLayers[layer._leaflet_id] = layer;

        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(p.x, p.y);
        if (layer._tilt !== 0) {
            ctx.rotate( layer._tilt );
        }
        if (s !== 1) {
            ctx.scale(1, s);
        }

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.restore();

        this._fillStroke(ctx, layer);
    },
});

L.Ellipse = L.Path.extend({

    options: {
        fill: true,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 359.9
    },

    initialize: function (latlng, radii, tilt, options) {

        L.setOptions(this, options);
        this._latlng = L.latLng(latlng);

        if (tilt) {
            this._tiltDeg = tilt;
        } else {
            this._tiltDeg = 0;
        }

        if (radii) {
            this._mRadiusX = radii[0];
            this._mRadiusY = radii[1];
        }
    },

    setRadius: function (radii) {
        this._mRadiusX = radii[0];
        this._mRadiusY = radii[1];
        return this.redraw();
    },

    getRadius: function () {
        return new L.point(this._mRadiusX, this._mRadiusY);
    },

    setTilt: function (tilt) {
        this._tiltDeg = tilt;
        return this.redraw();
    },

    getBounds: function () {
        // TODO respect tilt (bounds are too big)
        var lngRadius = this._getLngRadius(),
            latRadius = this._getLatRadius(),
            latlng = this._latlng;

        return new L.LatLngBounds(
            [latlng.lat - latRadius, latlng.lng - lngRadius],
            [latlng.lat + latRadius, latlng.lng + lngRadius]);
    },

    // @method setLatLng(latLng: LatLng): this
    // Sets the position of a circle marker to a new location.
    setLatLng: function (latlng) {
        this._latlng = L.latLng(latlng);
        this.redraw();
        return this.fire('move', {latlng: this._latlng});
    },

    // @method getLatLng(): LatLng
    // Returns the current geographical position of the circle marker
    getLatLng: function () {
        return this._latlng;
    },

    setStyle: L.Path.prototype.setStyle,

    _project: function () {
        var lngRadius = this._getLngRadius(),
            latRadius = this._getLatRadius(),
            latlng = this._latlng,
            pointLeft = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint([latlng.lat, latlng.lng - lngRadius]),
            pointBelow = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint([latlng.lat - latRadius, latlng.lng]);

        this._point = this._map.latLngToLayerPoint(latlng);
        this._radiusX = Math.max(this._point.x - pointLeft.x, 1);
        this._radiusY = Math.max(pointBelow.y - this._point.y, 1);
        this._tilt = Math.PI * this._tiltDeg / 180;
        this._endPointParams = this._centerPointToEndPoint();
        this._updateBounds();
    },

    _updateBounds: function () {
        // http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91132/how-to-get-the-limits-of-rotated-ellipse
        var sin = Math.sin(this._tilt);
        var cos = Math.cos(this._tilt);
        var sinSquare = sin * sin;
        var cosSquare = cos * cos;
        var aSquare = this._radiusX * this._radiusX;
        var bSquare = this._radiusY * this._radiusY;
        var halfWidth = Math.sqrt(aSquare*cosSquare+bSquare*sinSquare);
        var halfHeight = Math.sqrt(aSquare*sinSquare+bSquare*cosSquare);
        var w = this._clickTolerance();
        var p = [halfWidth + w, halfHeight + w];
        this._pxBounds = new L.Bounds(this._point.subtract(p), this._point.add(p));
    },

    _update: function () {
        if (this._map) {
            this._updatePath();
        }
    },

    _updatePath: function () {
        this._renderer._updateEllipse(this);
    },

    _getLatRadius: function () {
        return (this._mRadiusY / 40075017) * 360;
    },

    _getLngRadius: function () {
        return ((this._mRadiusX / 40075017) * 360) / Math.cos((Math.PI / 180) * this._latlng.lat);
    },

    _centerPointToEndPoint: function () {
        // Convert between center point parameterization of an ellipse
        // too SVG's end-point and sweep parameters.  This is an
        // adaptation of the perl code found here:
        // http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/SVG_Essentials/Paths
        var c = this._point,
            rx = this._radiusX,
            ry = this._radiusY,
            theta2 = (this.options.startAngle + this.options.endAngle) * (Math.PI / 180),
            theta1 = this.options.startAngle * (Math.PI / 180),
            delta = this.options.endAngle,
            phi = this._tiltDeg * (Math.PI / 180);

        // Determine start and end-point coordinates
        var x0 = c.x + Math.cos(phi) * rx * Math.cos(theta1) +
            Math.sin(-phi) * ry * Math.sin(theta1);
        var y0 = c.y + Math.sin(phi) * rx * Math.cos(theta1) +
            Math.cos(phi) * ry * Math.sin(theta1);

        var x1 = c.x + Math.cos(phi) * rx * Math.cos(theta2) +
            Math.sin(-phi) * ry * Math.sin(theta2);
        var y1 = c.y + Math.sin(phi) * rx * Math.cos(theta2) +
            Math.cos(phi) * ry * Math.sin(theta2);

        var largeArc = (delta > 180) ? 1 : 0;
        var sweep = (delta > 0) ? 1 : 0;

        return {'x0': x0, 'y0': y0, 'tilt': phi, 'largeArc': largeArc,
            'sweep': sweep, 'x1': x1, 'y1': y1};
    },

    _empty: function () {
        return this._radiusX && this._radiusY && !this._renderer._bounds.intersects(this._pxBounds);
    },

    _containsPoint : function (p) {
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946187/point-and-ellipse-rotated-position-test-algorithm
        var sin = Math.sin(this._tilt);
        var cos = Math.cos(this._tilt);
        var dx = p.x - this._point.x;
        var dy = p.y - this._point.y;
        var sumA = cos * dx + sin * dy;
        var sumB = sin * dx - cos * dy;
        return sumA * sumA / (this._radiusX * this._radiusX)  + sumB * sumB / (this._radiusY * this._radiusY) <= 1;
    }
});

export const lellipse = function (latlng, radii, tilt, options) {
    return new L.Ellipse(latlng, radii, tilt, options);
};
```

To create an ellipse to use with `react-leaflet`, I followed the example of [`Circle` in `react-leaflet`](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Circle.js) to produce the following `Ellipse` component:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { lellipse as LeafletEllipse } from '../l.ellipse';
import Path from './Path'
import children from './propTypes/children'
import latlng from './propTypes/latlng'
import type { LatLng, MapLayerProps, PathOptions } from './types'

type LeafletElement = LeafletEllipse
type Props = {
  center: LatLng,
  mSemiMajorAxis: number,
  mSemiMinorAxis: number,
  degreeTiltFromWest: number,
} & MapLayerProps &
  PathOptions &
  Object

export default class Ellipse extends Path<LeafletElement, Props> {
  static propTypes = {
    center: latlng.isRequired,
    mSemiMajorAxis: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    mSemiMinorAxis: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    degreeTiltFromWest: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    children: children,
  }

  createLeafletElement(props: Props): LeafletElement {
    const { center, mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis, degreeTiltFromWest, ...options } = props
    return new LeafletEllipse(center, [mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis], this.getOptions(options))
  }

  updateLeafletElement(fromProps: Props, toProps: Props) {
    if (toProps.center !== fromProps.center) {
      this.leafletElement.setLatLng(toProps.center);
    }
    if (toProps.degreeTiltFromWest !== fromProps.degreeTiltFromWest) {
      this.leafletElement.setTilt(toProps.degreeTiltFromWest);
    }
    if (toProps.mSemiMinorAxis !== fromProps.mSemiMinorAxis || toProps.mSemiMajorAxis !== fromProps.mSemiMajorAxis) {
      this.leafletElement.setRadius([toProps.mSemiMajorAxis, toProps.mSemiMinorAxis]);
    }

  }
}
```

The problem with the code is that it does not render an ellipse and it does not throw any errors. Could someone suggest how to render an ellipse with `react-leaflet`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *createLeafletElement* function is missing the tilt parameter. It should be:

```
   createLeafletElement(props) {
        const { center, mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis, degreeTiltFromWest, ...options } = props
        return new LeafletEllipse(center, [mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis], degreeTiltFromWest, this.getOptions(options))
    }
```

See below for the complete file (in ES6 rather than in typescript, as I find it clearer).

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { lellipse as LeafletEllipse } from './l.ellipse';
import { Path, withLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet';

class Ellipse extends Path {

    static propTypes = {
        center: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number).isRequired,
        mSemiMajorAxis: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        mSemiMinorAxis: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        degreeTiltFromWest: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    }

    createLeafletElement(props) {
        const { center, mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis, degreeTiltFromWest, ...options } = props
        return new LeafletEllipse(center, [mSemiMajorAxis, mSemiMinorAxis], degreeTiltFromWest, this.getOptions(options))
    }

    updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
        if (toProps.center !== fromProps.center) {
            this.leafletElement.setLatLng(toProps.center);
        }
        if (toProps.degreeTiltFromWest !== fromProps.degreeTiltFromWest) {
            this.leafletElement.setTilt(toProps.degreeTiltFromWest);
        }
        if (toProps.mSemiMinorAxis !== fromProps.mSemiMinorAxis || toProps.mSemiMajorAxis !== fromProps.mSemiMajorAxis) {
            this.leafletElement.setRadius([toProps.mSemiMajorAxis, toProps.mSemiMinorAxis]);
        }
    }
} 
export default class withLeaflet(Ellipse);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127627/how-to-make-an-ellipse-in-react-leaflet this post has a complete updated example