# Attempted import error: 'withLeaflet' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'

Tags: reactjs, npm, leaflet, react-leaflet

**Code:**

```
import { withLeaflet} from "react-leaflet";
```

I just want to import the withLeaflet but it gives me this error

**Error:**

```
Attempted import error: 'withLeaflet' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'.
```

**package.json >dependencies**

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
"leaflet": "^1.7.1",
"leaflet-rotatedmarker": "^0.2.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-leaflet": "^3.0.2",
"react-leaflet-rotatedmarker": "^0.1.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
```

Comment: you using react-leaflet 3, you no longer use withLeaflet, you need to use their hooks instead.

Comment: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#hooks

Comment: @Someone Special Thank you so much you was right

Comment: So how do you change that code to work on v3? Can you please show that? I don't understand the documentation on hooks there, not sure what to do to make this work.